# autohotkey - Trying to delete random items in Listbox

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying a parsing loop, this works good except I can't delete the first item in the list. Probably something to do with the backtick n. Can't figure it out yet!

Update - OK, needed to duplicate the StringReplace line without a backtick n, so as to get the first item in the list.

```
Gui, Add, ListBox, 8 x26 y37 w100 h100 vColorChoice, Red|Green|Blue|Black|White
Gui +Delimiter`n
Gui, Add, Button, Default, Delete
Gui, show
return


ButtonDelete:
Gui, Submit, NoHide
ControlGet, ListBoxContents, List,, ListBox1
StringReplace, ListBoxContents, ListBoxContents, |, `n, All
msgbox %ColorChoice% ; ColorChoice here contains the files selected to delete
Loop, Parse, ColorChoice, `n
{
    StringReplace, ListBoxContents, ListBoxContents, %A_LoopField%`n
    StringReplace, ListBoxContents, ListBoxContents, %A_LoopField%
    msgbox %ListBoxContents%
}
GuiControl,, ColorChoice, `n%ListBoxContents%
return

GuiClose:
ExitApp
```

Comment: Instead of using StringReplace to delete combined selection (e.g., `"Green|Black"`), loop over each of the selected items (`Green` and `Black`) and delete them individually from the ListBoxContents. Also, it doesn't work on the first item because you're trying to replace `"|Red"` which doesn't occur in `"Red|Green|Blue|Black|White"`

Comment: What delete command is available for the ListBox? The above Update is using the line position number instead of the text. Can I use text directly?